# how can I combine update and select query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to run this query that is to update the table row by setting score as 1 ,where the transactionid is maximum

```
UPDATE transaction_db SET score=1 WHERE transaction_id = ( SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM transaction_db );
```

> ERROR:Table 'transaction_db' is specified twice, both as a target for
>   'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `limit`:

```
update transaction_db 
set score = 1 
order by transaction_id desc
limit 1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a14bc9/1)